# I want to create a Gradient Color

Tags: vb.net, xaml, gradient

[image]

That is my example code for solidColor, i want to create some gradient color for some stuff.
Can you guys give me some examples?

Comment: what are you actually pointing in the screen shot? The codes are really hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example. You demand for example so its for you :
 https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55727/A-Simple-Gradient-Editor-for-WPF-in-C

One more thing post codes avoid pictures.

Comment: The sample code is written in c# you can use online .net (c# to vb converter) or do it himself.

Comment: Please do not give answers that only link to the answer. The core of the answer should be on stackoverflow